# Guaranteeing child component's height is >= sibling child component's

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to do this dynamically. I have a parent component which has two children components. Each children is nested inside its own div. Both children can update and, due to their content's nature, change height independently. I want to guarantee child component 1 div always has equal or greater height than child component 2. When it doesn't, I want it to dynamically change to match its sibling. The code:

```
class Parent extends Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="childComponent1wrapper">
                <ChildComponent1/>
            </div>

            <div className="childComponent2wrapper">
                <ChildComponent2/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I thought about saving each children component's height in a store and passing the prop to parent component as a prop, but it seems  overkill.
I've tried using parent's onComponentDidUpdate() but it doesn't trigger when children update.

How could I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Why not use css for that? You should search for flexbox.

Comment: @Dekel Child component 2 is a sticky element. It will dynamically leave its place and assume position:fixed when scrolling. I've tried making a table layout but no luck due to this. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into the flexbox anyway, but I don't think it will work without a dynamic javascript given the "sticky" situation. (No pun intended)